# Rails: optimizing a controller action (security checking)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, security, model-view-controller

I have an action in a controller that looks like this:

```
  def show
    @project = current_customer.projects.where(id: params[:project_id]).first
    if @project
      @feature = @project.features.where(id: params[:feature_id]).first
      if @feature
        @conversation = @feature.conversations.where(id: params[:id]).first
        unless @conversation
          head 401
        end
      else
        head 401
      end
    else
      head 401
    end
  end
```

The problem is the repetition of `head 401`. Is there a better way to write this action ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would write it like this

```
def show
  @project = current_customer.projects.where(id: params[:project_id]).first
  @feature = @project.features.where(id: params[:feature_id]).first if @project
  @conversation = @feature.conversations.where(id: params[:id]).first if @feature

  # error managment
  head 401 unless @conversation      
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have another related question, can I use CanCan for error managment in this action? It is a good idea ?

Comment: @Alex I've never used CanCan, I can't help you on this one.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can refactor  in your project model with something like this

```
Model Project
  ...
def get_conversation
  feature = features.where(id: params[:feature_id]).first
  conversation = feature.conversations.where(id: params[:id]).first if feature
end
```

And in your Controller

```
Controller ProjectController
def show
  @project = current_customer.projects.where(id: params[:project_id]).first
  @conversation = @project.get_conversation

  head 401 unless @conversation
end
```